# How to work with events in case of engine living inside thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, events

So I have thread `A` that is events initiator (network/gui). I have an Engine in thread `B` which runs in some `run()` function and updates on `update()` call. I wonder how to implement events on top of such structure. problem here is I get something like

- a mutex per event
- a vector per event
- 2 functions per event - one to fill vector one by one item, one to empty it and insert new data into engine.

so I have pseudocode like this **for each event**:

```
boost::mutex SomeEventMutex;
std::vector< T > SomeEventFrameData;
void ThreadASendsSomeEvent(T data)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(SomeEventMutex);
    SomeEventFrameData.push_back(data);
}

void ParseIncomeDartaFromSomeEvent()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(SomeEventMutex);
    BOOST_FOREACH(T dataItem, SomeEventFrameData)
    {
        // here can be some more complex operation with given data
        engine->DoStuff(dataItem);
    }
    SomeEventFrameData.clear();
}

void run()
{
    while(1){
        // for each event type
        ParseIncomeDartaFromSomeEvent();
        //Engine Update
        update();
    }
}
```

that looks so bad... I wonder if there are common solution for such problems? futher more I do not get how to make this event into object/class not making its creation and setup even more messier...(